# How can I write a C++ COM object with asynchronous event firing (like VB6's Timer object)?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, timer, com, vb6

I'm writing a C++ COM object for directory change notifications via `ReadDirectoryChangesW`. A thread in my object will wait for changes, then notify the VB6 client.

I know how to trigger events from the main thread of my program, similar to callback functions, but I don't want to force the user to poll my object for changes every small interval.

As far as I'm aware, what I want could be done by sending window messages, but this needs form subclassing on the VB6 side, which is quite complicated.

So I'm looking for a way to write an object like VB6's `Timer` which can fire an event in VB6 even when VB6 isn't currently calling into a method of `Timer`. Is this possible?

Comment: Native [Timers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644901(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: The question is not about the timer, just for firing events (a COM mechanism) asynchronously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COM events.

The topic is rather laborious, it implies defining a 'sink' interface that the event consumer (VB) is passing to the event source, and then raising events by calling methods on the 'sunken' interface. See [Architecture of Connectable Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686567(v=vs.85).aspx). You must implement [`IConnectionPointContainer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683857(v=vs.85).aspx). The good news is that IDEs are fully aware of this model and will expose your events in the VB designer. From the VB side will be as simple as a double-click on the COM object 'events' properties panel.

As for the 'async' part, this falls in the 'threading' model of your component and the VB host app. In Apartment threads (the default) you will have to raise the events in the main Apartment thread, and you *may* have to marshal the interface between threads. See [What are the rules for CoMarshalInterface and CoUnmarshalInterface?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20151022-00/?p=91301).

The details about asynchronous COM event firing from C++ server to VB6 client can be found in [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9506/Understanding-The-COM-Single-Threaded-Apartment).

Comment: But how does `Timer` do that? I can do `Timer1.Interval = 1000`, `Timer1.Enabled = True` and one second later the `Timer1_Timer()` event gets called in the main thread. Some code must have posted the event to the main thread's event queue, but this code cannot be in the main thread because the main thread is simply in a `DoEvents` loop (processing its event queue). So how does does this entry get posted in the event queue?

Comment: It uses a message, WM_TIMER.  Just as you'll use a message when you marshal the interface pointer and raise the event, the COM plumbing takes care of that.

Comment: This is not only laborious but working out the exact steps is quite hardcore. Luckily, and only with the input from both of you, I was able to find an article which deals with async COM events and have added the relevant link to complete the answer.